# update data into mysql database by clicking on a link using PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

Is there a way to update data in a MySQL DB when the user clicks on a link? 
I'm creating a voting app. It allows users to store questions to be used instantly or for a later use. When the user is viewing his created questions, he/she can click on a link that will update a column in the database that will store either 1 or 0 based on the question ID. (1 means that the question is available to vote and 0 is the opposite). I have written the code to retrieve questions from the DB. and now I am trying to write the code that will update question data by clicking on a link.

**What I can't figure is how to get the question ID where the user clicked the link so then I can update the DB.**
Excuse me if my explanation is not clear. English is my second language and I was trying hard to communicate this better.

Comment: You should store id in a hidden input value if you don't want use ajax.

Comment: @Siamak.A.M , how can I get the question ID to store it? that is what I'm trying to figure how.

Comment: What is your QUESTIONS table structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php
        $username = $_COOKIE['username'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS WHERE username ='$username'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());    
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        //---------- new
        if(isset($_GET['voteID']))
        {
            $viteID = (int) $_GET['voteID'];
            // your update query
        }

        //--------  
            ?> 
            <table width="50%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                <tr><td><b>Question ID</b></td><td><b>Question</b></td><td><b>Active/Inactive</b></td></tr>
                <?php
                $html = '';
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                    $html .= '<tr>';
                    $html .= '<td>' . $row[0] . '</td>';
                    $html .= '<td>' . $row[1] . '</td>'; 
                    $activity = $row[3];

                    // ---- new
                    $html .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?id='.$row[0].'">Vote Up</a>';               
                    //-------

                    //if active = 1, do the following
                    if ($activity == 1) {
                        $html .= '<td>' . '<a href=markAsInActive.php>Active</a>' . '</td>';
                    } else {
                        $html .= '<td>' . 'Inactive' . '</td>';
                    }
                    $html .='</tr>';

                }
                echo $html;
                ?>
            </table>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: It updates the DB by clicking buttons not links. Anyway, thanks. I'm gonna use it for now.

Comment: Answer edited for links and If the answer is helpful accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<td><a href='markAsInActive.php?id=$row[0]'>Active</a></td>";
```

I'm just guessing that `$row[0]` is the ID -- you can change that to the appropriate column for your database (it's usually preferable to use `mysql_fetch_assoc` so you can access columns by name instead of meaningless column numbers).

The PHP script can then use `$_GET['row']` to get the ID that should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need add an html form element.

```
<from action="yourURL.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="userInput" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Now your information comes to you as:

```
 $info = $_POST['userInput'];
```

So then write an UPDATE query to put the user info into the record.

Comment: Hi, I considered doing this. However, I don't want my users every time they want to mark their questions as active to memorize question ID's. I want it to be done automatically by the system.

Comment: The just use javaScript to post the form for you when an input changes. You can post to the same fprm name or create a separate handler.php that handles it in the background with an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

- My first suggestion is to use the `mysql_fetch_assoc` function instead of `mysql_fetch_row` function.
- Now, change the anchor link as `"markAsInActive.php?id={$row[0]}"` instead of `markAsInActive.php` such as

`echo "<td><a href='markAsInActive.php?id={$row[0]}'>Active</a></td>";`

- In your 'markAsInactive.php', you can write as following.

  ```
  $sql = "UPDATE `QUESTIONS` SET `is_active`='0' WHERE `ID` = {$_GET['id']}";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  ```

assuming that the primary key of the `QUESTIONS` table is `ID` and the activity flag column of the table is `is_active`.